# I want to produce Link with a path for sharing limages

Tags: path, github-pages

I have a folder which have a construction below.

```
images_folder1/  
    ├image01.png  
    ├image02.png  
images_folder2/  
    ├image01.png  
    ├image02.png
```

I want to upload these folders and get the link to access and I hope that the link has something like a relative path or absolute path.
(ex: https://〇〇//images_folder1/image01.png)

I already tried to use Github to accomplish this goal. Actually Github enables me to get the link with a path structure like "https://github.com/User/test_repo/blob/main/images_folder1/image01.png".
but the images should not be seen to other people except for those who know the link.(Github's private repository cannot do this. I have to get the repository "public") That's why Github is not suitable.

Also, I came up with the idea to get the link by using online storage services like "Box" but the link that I can get via Box seemed to be encrypted.(I mean there are no relationship between the folder structure and the link itself.)

Are there anyone who know the best websites or applications suitable for my requirements?
It is the first time to ask questions via stack overflow and I'm Japanese, so there might be some expressions hard to understand or sentences that don't contain sufficient explanations. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub also gives you a relative or absolute path for your image other than url like `https://github.com/User/test_repo/blob/main/images_folder1/image01.png`. Just make sure, the url path you have given is correct. As:

- If your GitHub pages site is publised at  `abc.github.io` then type `abc.github.io/images_folder1/image01.png`.
- If your GitHub pages site is publised at  `abc.github.io/repository` then type `abc.github.io/repository/images_folder1/image01.png`.
  ***Note*: Make sure that no "/" is used at the end of the image, or page, url. Such that `abc.github.io/images_folder1/image01.png/` should not be used instead of "`abc.github.io/images_folder1/image01.png`" , otherwise it will throw an error.**

**EDIT**:

- Suppose your GitHub username is "abc".
- And you create a repository named "tiger", and turn GitHub pages on from the setting.(If your repository is private then you will need to upgrade to a premium account to active GitHub Pages)
- Then your GitHub Pages will be published at "`https://abc.github.io/tiger`",i.e.,
  ("https://your-username.github.io/repository-name") by default and the "index.html" file will work as your homepage.[image: GitHub repository name]
- And if you repository name is "tiger.github.io" instead of only tiger, then your GitHub Pages will be published at "`https://tiger.github.io`",i.e.,
  ("https://repository-name.github.io").[image: GitHub repository name]
- But of you want to connect it to a custom top-level domain then you can do it from the settings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I couldn't understand because of the lack of the information I have now, but I don't know what "abc.githu.io" is as well as how I can get to know my GitHub account is published at "abc.github.io" or "abc.github.io/repository"

Comment: I have edited the answer, explaining  about the repository publication. By the way you can  go to "Settings" of the repository, and then go to "Pages" tab to see where your GitHub Page is published at. And make sure to read the note mentioned in the answer (which is mentioned before the 'Edit').

Comment: Thank you for everything. I could solve the problem.